# Get only unique elements from two lists

Tags: python, list, unique

If I have two lists (may be with different len):

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
f = [1,11,22,33,44,3,4]

result = [11,22,33,44]
```

im doing:

```
for element in f:
    if element in x:
        f.remove(element)
```

I'm getting

```
result = [11,22,33,44,4]
```

Comment: Why isn't `2` part of your output?  FWIW, what you are doing is `f - x` whereas what you want is `(f \cup x) - (f \cap x)`

Answer (score 62):

### UPDATE:

Thanks to @[Ahito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9234206/ahito):

```py
In : list(set(x).symmetric_difference(set(f)))

Out: [33, 2, 22, 11, 44]
```

[This article](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/symmetric_difference) has a neat diagram that explains what the symmetric difference does.

### OLD answer:

Using this piece of [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) on sets:

```
>>> # Demonstrate set operations on unique letters from two words
...
>>> a = set('abracadabra')
>>> b = set('alacazam')
>>> a                                  # unique letters in a
{'a', 'r', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
>>> a - b                              # letters in a but not in b
{'r', 'd', 'b'}
>>> a | b                              # letters in a or b or both
{'a', 'c', 'r', 'd', 'b', 'm', 'z', 'l'}
>>> a & b                              # letters in both a and b
{'a', 'c'}
>>> a ^ b                              # letters in a or b but not both
{'r', 'd', 'b', 'm', 'z', 'l'}
```

I came up with this piece of code to obtain unique elements from two lists:

```
(set(x) | set(f)) - (set(x) & set(f))
```

or slightly modified to return `list`:

```
list((set(x) | set(f)) - (set(x) & set(f))) #if you need a list
```

Here:

1. `|` operator returns elements in `x`, `f` or **both**
2. `&` operator returns elements in **both** `x` and `f`
3. `-` operator subtracts the results of `&` from `|` and provides us with the elements that are uniquely presented only in one of the lists

Comment: Should this be marked as the accepted answer?  Any unforeseen unintended with it?

Comment: This code passed a serious stress test. Should be gtg.

Comment: Iopheam - Thank you

Comment: Spelled with a "y", not an "i". `list(set(x).symmetric_difference(set(f)))`

Comment: `sorted(set(result))` also returns a list object as well.

Answer (score 26):

If you want the unique elements from both lists, this should work:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
f = [1,11,22,33,44,3,4]

res = list(set(x+f))
print(res)
# res = [1, 2, 3, 4, 33, 11, 44, 22]
```

Comment: But this does not answer the OP question at all!

Comment: @lifebalance how do you say that ?!!

Comment: @JeruLuke because the questions specifies they need this answer `[11,22,33,44,4]`, not `[1, 2, 3, 4, 33, 11, 44, 22]`

Comment: @YegorKryukov Thanks for correcting me. I didn't pay attention to the question.

Answer (score 18):

Based on the clarification of this question in a [new (closed) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098206/unique-values-between-2-lists#45098206):

If you want all items from the second list that do not appear in the first list you can write:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
f = [1,11,22,33,44,3,4]

result = set(f) - set(x) # correct elements, but not yet in sorted order
print(sorted(result)) # sort and print

# Output: [11, 22, 33, 44]
```

Answer (score 7):

if you want to get  only unique elements from the two list then you can get it by..

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b= [2,4,1]
list(set(a) - set(b))
OP:- [3, 5]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]

f = [1, 11, 22, 33, 44, 3, 4]

list(set(x) ^ set(f))

[33, 2, 22, 11, 44]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: What does the ^ do?

Answer (score 6):

**Input :**

```
x = [1,2,3,4]

f = [1,11,22,33,44,3,4]
```

**Code:**

```
l = list(set(x).symmetric_difference(set(f)))
print(l)
```

**Output :**

```
[2, 22, 33, 11, 44]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your method won't get the unique element "2".  What about:

```
list(set(x).intersection(f))
```

Comment: Almost right, but you got it backwards. Try symmetric_difference() instead.

Comment: "Unique elements from both lists" sounds like intersection to me. Questioner should clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Simplified Version & in support of [@iopheam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3983070/iopheam)'s answer.

## Use `Set` Subtraction.

```py
# original list values
x = [1,2,3,4]
f = [1,11,22,33,44,3,4]

# updated to set's
y = set(x)  # {1, 2, 3, 4}
z = set(f)  # {1, 33, 3, 4, 11, 44, 22}

# parsed to the result variable
result = z - y  # {33, 11, 44, 22}

# printed using the sorted() function to display as requested/stated by the op.
print(f"Result of f - x: {sorted(result)}")
# Result of f - x: [11, 22, 33, 44]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v_child_value = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'v':22}, {'bb':23}]
shop_by_cat_sub_cats = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'bbb':222}, {'bb':23}]


unique_sub_cats = []
for ind in shop_by_cat_sub_cats:
    if ind not in v_child_value:
        unique_sub_cats.append(ind)
```

> unique_sub_cats = [{'bbb': 222}]

Answer (score 0):

Python code to create a unique list from two lists :

```
a=[1,1,2,3,5,1,8,13,6,21,34,55,89,1,2,3]
b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,2,3,4]
m=list(dict.fromkeys([a[i] for i in range(0,len(a)) if a [i] in a and a[i] in b and a[i]]))

print(m)
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, as code-only answers are not allowed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
L=[] 
For i in x:
    If i not in f:
        L. Append(I)
For i in f:
    If I not in x:
        L. Append(I)
Return L
```