# unique values between 2 lists

Tags: python, list, unique

I am trying to find unique values b/w 2 lists but this logic doesn't seems to work

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
f = [1,11,22,33,44,3,4]
for element in f:
    if element in x:
        f.remove(element)
print f
```

desired output

```
[11, 22, 33, 44]
```

actual output

```
[11, 22, 33, 44, 4]
```

[Get only unique elements from two lists python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444561/get-only-unique-elements-from-two-lists-python)

same ask here
solution:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
f = [1,11,22,33,44,3,4]

res = list(set(x+f))
print(res)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 33, 11, 44, 22]
```

as you can see its adding 1,2,3,4 not output I need

Comment: The same question with the exact same sample data has already been asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444561/get-only-unique-elements-from-two-lists-python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444561/get-only-unique-elements-from-two-lists-python

question is same but output is different all answers over ther dont giving unique values but merging lists and using set()

Comment: I voted to reopen because, in contrast to the other question, this one stated the desired behavior which is different from the behavior in the answers given there. (There may be another dup, though.)

Comment: there's a dupe somewhere no doubt, here's a not super efficient solution  `[i for i in f if i not in x]`

Comment: I answered your original question ([clicky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45098345/4349415)) - you should be more specific and edit the original question if it needs clarification instead of posting the same question again as a different user.

Comment: @mpf82 The question you answered was asked in 2015. I don't think it is by the same author.

Comment: @kazemakase oh, my bad, I was only looking at the sample data, not at the date.

Comment: @mpf82 I used these values as sample code as that user did, and that page has not single verified answer and output and answers over there are completely different

Comment: @mpf82 I guess the OP read that question but did not find a satisfactory answer there, so asked it again in a different way. Seems legitimate to me.

Comment: @AhsanNaseem Hint for the future: Indicate the research you did from the beginning. If you link to another question and explain why it is different for you we can avoid a lot of trouble :)

Comment: @Chris_Rands thanks it helps alot!

Comment: @kazemakase thanks will do that :)

Comment: @kazemakase I agree so I reopened.

Comment: @kazemakase thanks much appreciated time you put into this

Comment: @ayhan You can close it again if you want ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125909/python-find-elements-in-one-list-that-are-not-in-the-other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After all the hassle with closing and re-opening I feel someone ought to actually answer the question.

There are different ways to achieve the desired result:

1. List comprehensions: `[i for i in f if i not in x]`. Maybe less efficient but preserves order. Credit goes to [Chris_Rands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6260170/chris-rands) (comment above).
2. Set operations: `set(f) - set(x)`. Likely more efficient for larger lists but does not preserve order. Gredit goes to [mpf82](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45098345/3005167). This also removes duplicates in `f`, as pointed out by [asongtoruin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5309300/asongtoruin).

Comment: There's another important comment to make about using sets - if an item appears twice in `f` but not at all in `x`, it will only appear once in the output list. The list comprehension would result in the item appearing twice.

Comment: @asongtoruin good point. Thank you.