# Get unique string from two lists python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to get unique string from two list. i tried this [Get only unique elements from two lists python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444561/get-only-unique-elements-from-two-lists-python) 
but it is working for only numbers

```
a  = ['st','ac','vf']
b = ['st']
```

output required:

```
c =['ac','vf']
```

Comment: `print(list(set(a) -set(b)))`

Comment: If the first list contained `['st','st','ac','vf']`, would `st` also appear in the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use that as well:

```
list(set(a).difference(set(b)))
```

Result:

> ['ac', 'vf']

**EDIT:**

In order to make it more robust you can have something like the foloowing:

```
def diff_lists(l1, l2):
    if len(l1) > len(l2):
        return list(set(l1).difference(set(l2)))
    elif len(l2) > len(l1):
        return list(set(l2).difference(set(l1)))
    else:
        return list(set(l1).difference(set(l2)))
```

Then it doesn't matter whether you call

```
diff_lists(a, b)
```

or

```
diff_lists(b,a)
```

The result will still be the same as above.