# How can I remove the same values from arrays and put the remnants in two different arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I have two arrays with string values, they have similar values and different ones, how can I remove the same values from them and put the remnants in two different arrays?
Example from below

```
one_ar = ['Python', 'Java', 'C']
two_ar = ['Python', 'Lua']

one_result = ['Java', 'C']
two_result = ['Lua']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get only unique elements from two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444561/get-only-unique-elements-from-two-lists)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple solution would be

```
one_result = [x in one_ar if x not in two_ar]
two_result = [x in two_ar if x not in one_ar]
```

If you need it with efficient scaling to large size, you might prefer something else.